# Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). When calling onChange function in antd Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm getting `` Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. `` warning in my select component

```
                            <GroupedSelect
                              value={where === 14 ? whereEntityId : where}
                              options={availableWhereTypes}
                              onChange={value => {
                                if (typeof value === 'string') {
                                  handleCharacteristicChange(
                                    value,
                                    index,
                                    conditionIndex,
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  handleWhereTypeChange(
                                    value,
                                    index,
                                    conditionIndex,
                                  );
                                }
                              }}
                            />
```

Both `handleCharacteristicChange` and  `handleWhereTypeChange` call `setState` . If I remove the `if else` from `onChange` function the error is gone. The component itself seems to work correctly but I would like to get rid of the warning message.

The select component is from `antd` with slight modifications

Answer (score 0):

We're updating state and references to state during a render, which will cause unnecessary and rather duplicated re-renders.

I think [`React#useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) should help here to memoize our callback.

You can inline this I didn't just for clarity (I'm assuming you're mapping these).

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';

const onChange = useCallback(value => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    handleCharacteristicChange(
      value,
      index,
      conditionIndex,
    );
  } else {
    handleWhereTypeChange(
      value,
      index,
      conditionIndex,
    );
  }
}, [value, index, conditionIndex]);

return (
  <GroupedSelect
    value={where === 14 ? whereEntityId : where}
    options={availableWhereTypes}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
);
```